# Are there any non-contraction you-plural words in English besides 'yourselves'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can only think of `yourselves` as a single word that is related to (only) you-plural and isn't a verb. The other one I can think of is `y'all` but that's more of a contraction.

Comment: In some regions you'ns is used.

Answer (score 0):

**You**, **your**, **yours**, and **yourselves** can all be [second person plural pronouns](http://www.mcwdn.org/grammar/propersonal.html).

Read this for list of [informal forms of you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You)

Comment: But you, your, and yours can can also be when addressing the singular 'you'. I meant distinctly multiple people, so plural-you. That's why I said `related to (only) you-plural`. Maybe I didn't ask this quite perfectly but I don't really know the language lingo

Comment: I misunderstood that part. Then yes, **yourselves** is the only form that cannot be used in the singular form.